# IOError on file deletion

Tags: c#, file, itext, watermark

The following code is used for watermarking pdf :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WaterDocument
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string FileLocation = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Hello.pdf";
          //  string watermarkedFile = "Watermarked.pdf";
            // Creating watermark on a separate layer
            // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to read the Existing PDF Document
            PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(FileLocation);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileLocation.Replace(".pdf","[temp][file].pdf"), FileMode.Create))
            // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper object to write Data from iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to FileStream object
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs))
            {
                // Getting total number of pages of the Existing Document
                int pageCount = reader1.NumberOfPages;

                // Create New Layer for Watermark
                PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("WatermarkLayer", stamper.Writer);
                // Loop through each Page
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    // Getting the Page Size
                    Rectangle rect = reader1.GetPageSize(i);

                    // Get the ContentByte object
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);

                    // Tell the cb that the next commands should be "bound" to this new layer
                    cb.BeginLayer(layer);
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(
                      BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 50);

                    PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
                    gState.FillOpacity = 0.25f;
                    cb.SetGState(gState);

                    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                    cb.BeginText();
                    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Confidential", rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 45f);
                    cb.EndText();

                    // Close the layer
                    cb.EndLayer();
                }
                stamper.Close();
            }

            File.Delete(FileLocation);  //error on this line
            File.Move(FileLocation.Replace(".pdf", "[temp][file].pdf"), FileLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

On this line I am getting the error

```
File.Delete(FileLocation);
```

It is throwing me the following error

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Desktop\Hello.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

How can I find the problem in my code?

Comment: Could you please close the file and then delete it? You might be opening it  in your code for doing some operation and not closing it. so please check that and try. Also check u r running VS in Admin mode.
is it possible to paste `iTextSharp` dlls here? if so please paste the dll here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling Close on the PdfReader object reader1, add this before the File.Delete call:

```
reader1.Close()
```

You should also consider adding a curly brace after this line:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileLocation.Replace(".pdf","[temp][file].pdf"), FileMode.Create))
```

There's a risk you add a line directly below that line and your code will stop working as the using statement is terminated directly on the row below.